# How can I enable vertical web page scrolling from within a horizontally scrollable area in mobile WebKit?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

We have the following HTML:

```
<div class="thumb-list">
    <ul class="thumb-list__inner">
        <li class="thumb">...</li>
        <li class="thumb">...</li>
        <li class="thumb">...</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.thumb-list {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

    .thumb-list__inner {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: 0;
    }

        .thumb {
            width: 75px;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            white-space: normal;
            margin-right: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 0.9375rem;
        }
```

This produces a horizontal list of items that extends beyond the edge of the viewport which is then scrollable horizontally to reveal more items.

This all works great, except in mobile Webkit browsers, where you can scroll the list horizontally but if you try to scroll the page vertically from within this element, you can't. If you scroll the page from any other element outside this, it's fine. The browser versions I've tested in are:

- Chrome 45.0.2454.89 on iOS 9.0.2
- Safari on iOS 9.0.2
- Default browser on Android 4.2.2
- Chrome 5.2.604591 on Android 4.2.2 (this won't scroll in any direction)

I have never encountered this issue before when using this method. The minimal information I've managed to find about this issue suggests that the browser is preventing scrolling in one axis when scrolling is explicitly defined on the other axis.

I've tried using libraries like [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com) but this wouldn't solve the issue.

I'm considering rewriting the functionality to use a carousel plugin or something similar. I'd rather not, as the CSS solution is the simplest. But at this stage I just need it to work!

Has anyone experienced and remedied this issue themselves?

Comment: So I've managed to overcome the issue. Whether I've remedied the cause or masked it, I'm not sure. But, I resolved it with strategic use of `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`. What I didn't know about this property, is that it creates new stacking contexts (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling), which I suspect had something to do with it. So I applied `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to the scrollable elements and then `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto` to descendant elements which had issues as a result.